# Count concurrent times

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have been asked by a group of physicians to count/calculate the peak number of concurrent cases on the weekends.  I have the start and stop times of each case in an Excel worksheet, and I need to count the concurrent cases and determine the highest value for each date.

Here's an example day's worth of data:

```
    A               B                  C
   Date         Case Start          Case End
2018-12-02   2018-12-02 03:39   2018-12-02 05:32
2018-12-02   2018-12-02 04:14   2018-12-02 05:52
2018-12-02   2018-12-02 11:45   2018-12-03 04:13
2018-12-02   2018-12-02 12:30   2018-12-03 01:01
2018-12-02   2018-12-02 17:05   2018-12-02 19:26
2018-12-02   2018-12-02 18:20   2018-12-02 19:48
2018-12-02   2018-12-02 19:10   2018-12-03 00:01
2018-12-02   2018-12-02 20:00   2018-12-02 21:43
2018-12-02   2018-12-02 20:11   2018-12-02 21:39
2018-12-02   2018-12-02 22:28   2018-12-02 23:20
```

Column A is fairly useless,
because it's just the day portion of the value in Column B
(but it does save me from having to generate that). 
Data are sorted by Column B. 
Trivially, for each Row *n*,
`Bn` < `Cn`.

<sup>[Here's an image of some more data.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gyA56.png)</sup>

I tried

```
=IF(COUNTIFS(B$2:B$10000, ">="&C2, C$2:C$10000, "<="&B2, D$2:D$9, "="&D2) > 1, "Overlap", "")
```

and I have tried

```
=SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(IF(B$2:B$16<=B2,IF(C$2:C$16>=B2,MATCH(A$2:A$16,A$2:A$16,0))),ROW(A$2:A$16)-ROW(A$2)+1),1))
```

I just do not know what changes to make to work with my data. 
I was doing copy and paste.

I have also used this language

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--($B$1:$B$10000<=B1),--($C$1:$C$10000>=B1))
```

which at least gave me some results and not errors.

Comment: Can you please share what you've tried, and some sample of the expected output?

Comment: =IF(COUNTIFS(B$2:B$10000, ">="&C2, C$2:C$10000, "<="&B2, D$2:D$9, "="&D2) > 1,  "Overlap",  "")  and I have tried =SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(IF(B$2:B$16<=B2,IF(C$2:C$16>=B2,MATCH(A$2:A$16,A$2:A$16,0))),ROW(A$2:A$16)-ROW(A$2)+1),1))  I just do not know what changes to make to work with my data.  I was doing copy and paste

Comment: i have also used this language which at least gave me some results and not errors   =SUMPRODUCT(--($B$1:$B$10000<=B1),--($C$1:$C$10000>=B1))

Comment: There is a problem with your data: cases started just before midnight end in the early hours of the same day! Is the date assigned to a case the start or end date?

Comment: @Sherry West - It would be better to [edit your question](https://superuser.com/posts/1447877/edit) to add information to it instead of using comments

Comment: I just realized that too.  My report was defaulting to start case date.

Comment: I suggest you provide your data in a format that allows pasting it for testing. Also, *OPINION*: dates in the shown format is prone to cause trouble IMO, use e.g. Fomat cell (CTRL+1) to set all dates to e.g. YYYY-MM-DD format.

Comment: 2018-12-02 2018-12-02 03:39:00 2018-12-02 05:32:00
2018-12-02 2018-12-02 04:14:00 2018-12-02 05:52:00
2018-12-02 2018-12-02 11:45:00 2018-12-03 04:13:00
2018-12-02 2018-12-02 12:30:00 2018-12-03 01:01:00
2018-12-02 2018-12-02 17:05:00 2018-12-02 19:26:00
2018-12-02 2018-12-02 18:20:00 2018-12-02 19:48:00
2018-12-02 2018-12-02 19:10:00 2018-12-03 00:01:00
2018-12-02 2018-12-02 20:00:00 2018-12-02 21:43:00
2018-12-02 2018-12-02 20:11:00 2018-12-02 21:39:00
2018-12-02 2018-12-02 22:28:00 2018-12-02 23:20:00

Comment: (1) One thing that struck me about your data is that you say it’s for a weekend, but December 3, 2018 was a Monday. (2) One of your examples of things you’ve tried refers to cells `D$2:D$9`.  What’s in them? (3) I suspect that I sort-of understand what you’re saying, but please try harder to *explain* (in English words and sentences) what you want to calculate. (4) Please give us a little more data *in text form.*  A few rows with date (case start) on December 3, some of which end on December 4, should be enough; I don’t believe that we need to see more than  … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  one weekend’s worth of data.  (If you believe that we need to see more than one weekend’s worth of data in order to understand the intricacies of the problem, then *say so* and *explain why.*) (5) As BruceWayne said, please show us some sample of the expected output.  This means *actual numbers* that correspond to the sample input data that you have provided.  You should probably explain how to compute those results manually. (6) How do you feel about VBA? … … (7) As cybernetic.nomad said, please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Comment: @SherryWest,, instead of comments  better you post all that as as Answer!!

Answer (score 0):

**You may use this method to calculate concurrent sessions and the time difference on Weekends for each Date:**

[image]

**How it works:**

- Formula in Cell `J168`:

  `=IF(OR(WEEKDAY(I168,2)=7,WEEKDAY(H168,2)=1),I168-H168,"")`

**N.B.** *Apply `hh:mm` Time Format on required data range in `Column J`.*

- Formula in Cell `K168`:

  `=IF(OR(WEEKDAY(I168,2)=7,WEEKDAY(H168,2)=1),COUNTIFS(H168:H$177,"<="&I168,C168:C$177,">="&B118,A168:A$177,"<>"&A168)+1,"")`

*Adjust cell references for both the Formulas as needed.*